# Performing processing after PDone

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow, apache-beam-io

Is there any way to utilize the result from the sink i.e. `PDone` for further processing, such as sending a message to Pub/Sub only when data has been fully written to GCS or all rows have been written to BigQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way in IOs to return PTransform after IO.write(). For example TextIO.write().withOutputFilenames(). But it is IO specific and so not every IO has such a API.

PDone cannot be used for further processing.